# Laravel 4 Form passing 2 parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Currently i'm working on a project to manage my cost on fuel.
Now i try to pass 2 parameters in a `Form::open()` which sadly doesn't work.
The reason why i think i need to pass 2 parameters at once is because my url is `Sitename/car/{id}/tank/{id}`
What am i doing wrong?

***edit.blade.php***

```
Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'method' => 'put', 'action' => array('TankController@update', array($aid, $id))))
```

Problem Code

```
'action' => array('TankController@update', array($aid, $id)
```

-Results in the following error:

`Parameter "tank" for route "car.{id}.tank.update" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.`

---

***TankController.php***

```
public function edit($id, $tid)
{
    $tank = Tank::find($tid);
    if(!$tank) return Redirect::action('TankController@index');
    return View::make('Tank.edit', $tank)->with('aid', $id);
}
public function update($id, $tid)
{
    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), Tank::$rules);
    if($validation->passes()){
        $tank = Tank::find($tid);
        $tank->kmstand          = Input::get('kmstand');
        $tank->volume           = Input::get('volume');
        $tank->prijstankbeurt   = Input::get('prijstankbeurt');
        $tank->datumtank        = Input::get('datumtank');
        $tank->save();

        return Redirect::action('TankController@index', $id)->with('success', 'Tankbeurt succesvol aangepast');
    } else return Redirect::action('TankController@edit', $id)->withErrors($validation);
}
```

***Route.php***

```
Route::resource('car', 'CarController');
Route::resource('car/{id}/tank', 'TankController');
Route::controller('/', 'UserController');
```

**-Url Structure**
SITENAME/car/2/tank/2/edit

I've also looked into the api documents but found nothing.
http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Html.FormBuilder.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'method' => 'put', 'action' => array('TankController@update', $aid, $id)))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the best solution

```
 Form::open (array ('method'=>'put', 'route'=>array($routeName [,params...]))
```

An example:

```
 {{ Form::open(array('route' => array('admin.myroute', $object->id))) }}
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/491

Comment: But you're only passing one parameter in your example. Passing two parameters that way doesn't work in 5.2.

Comment: The question is for Laravel 4 @AlexeyMezenin, but thanks for the info

Comment: @Sangar82, yes, but your current example uses one parameter and OP is asking about two parameters. Also, racl101 said it also works in Laravel 5.1, that's why I told it doesn't work in Laravel 5.2.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin [,params...] is for n parameters, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in your blade:

> For **Laravel 5.1**

```
 {!! Form::open([
          'route' => ['car.tank.update', $car->id, $tank->id],
          'method' => 'put',
          'class' => 'form-horizontal'
               ])
 !!}
```

Comment: In Laravel 5.x the form class is dropped. If you still want to use this HTML helpers like `Form` you can use the community-driven replacement [laravelcollective HTML](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html) class. Source: [Search for Form & HTML Helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.0)